# Wordpress wp_query instead of

Tags: wordpress

I have this function that displays the 5 most viewed posts.

in functions.php i have:

```
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

At the moment i'm using a **query_posts** method to display the 5 most viewed posts:

```
<?php
query_posts( array (
   'post_type' => 'post', 
   'showposts' => 5,
   'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   )
   );

   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>      
   <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And now I'm trying to achieve the same results by using wp_query, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the code i'm using for **wp_query**:

```
<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('showposts=5, meta_key=post_views_count, orderby=meta_value_num'); // exclude category 9
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>     


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

It just displays the 5 latest posts and not the 5 most viewed posts. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showsposts is no longer a valid parameter for WP_Query, from the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

> posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter).

As lorem monkey suggested, it's better to pass your parameters as an array as well.

```
<?php 

$args = array('posts_per_page'=>5,'meta_key'=>'post_views_count','orderby'=>'meta_value_num');
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>     


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query 

?>
```

Comment: Very glad it worked! Do you mind hitting the check mark next to the vote arrows so that future visitors know this was the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with your arguments as an array:

```
$wpq_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($wpq_args);
```

See the documentation for a few examples and all arguments: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query